# Not able to web deploy to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, webdeploy

I am trying to web deploy to a ec2 instance using the msbuild

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
/p:Configuration=Release;MsDeployServiceUrl=ec2-instance
```

name.compute.amazonaws.com:8172/msdeploy.axd;MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent;username="adminuser";password="password";DeployIisAppPath=Sitename;CreatePackageOnPublish=true;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=WebPublish
     "my.Web.csproj"

I get a

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web
.Publishing.targets(3847,5): error : Web deployment task failed.(Could not comp
lete the request to remote agent URL ':8172/msdeploy.axd/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE'.)  This error indicates that you cannot connect
 to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network sett
ings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and t
he appropriate services have been started on the server.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.P
ublishing.targets(3847,5): error : Error details:\r 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.P
ublishing.targets(3847,5): error : Could not complete the request to remote age
nt URL ':8172/msdeploy.a
xd/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE'.
```

I have 
1.Open ports in security group for 8172

2.Reinstalled web deploy 3 in target

3.Made a admin user and using that

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The URL its using is incorrect. Since you are publishing over the web you are using web management service and hence the url should be in either one of the following formats:

Publishing as an admin:

```
https://myserver.com:8172/msdeploy.axd
```

If you are publishing as an owner of one site on the server and have permissions just to your own site then:

```
https://myserver.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=<sitename>
```

Comment: Thanks Shaikh but I read that by default it is https so no need to add that.And when I do "https://myserver.com:8172/msdeploy.axd" it comes out as http://https://myserver.com:8172/msdeploy.axd in jenkins

Comment: The fact that it is showing: /MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE in the error means its not using the right protocol. Web Deploy publishes to web deploy agent service or to WMSvc. The decision is either explicit by user or if not specified, some assumptions are made based on the url passed. It seems that here it is resolving to use web deploy agent service which will not work. Specify the complete url with the site=<sitename> syntax